# Two LAN networks single internet connection

Tags: networking, router, internet, lan, wired-networking

I am in a situation where I need to use a single incoming Internet connection in the house for 2 different LAN networks: a wired network for the residents of the house and one for the small business below us. I want to make sure the residents can't communicate directly with the PC's on the business network. The question is: Do I need to buy 2 routers to make this possible? How would I arrange this, and do you have any recommendations on what brand I should go for?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you intend for the PC's on the business network to offer any internet-accessible services? (If they did, the residential PC's would be allowed to access them via their external IP address, right?)

Comment: Like servers etc? Thats not currently the plan, but I was more worried about any NASses or something

Comment: Right, no servers for now, good. So I think you want the two networks as isolated from each other as any other pair of non-related private networks which are both connected to the internet. Consider adjusting the question from "communicate with" to "communicate directly with" if you think it helps clarify.

Comment: Here's a description of how to set up a specific router with multiple downstream networks, but they *can* access each other, so it's not yet exactly what you want. I am optimistic that with one more configuration change it should be possible to isolate the networks so the router doesn't route between them. http://networkingforintegrators.com/2013/01/how-to-run-multiple-networks-from-a-mikrotik/

Comment: Here's a non-encouraging thread about isolating networks on a mikrotik RB750 router: http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=38734

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is **VLAN isolation.** It is not a common feature in "home" routers (because few home users need VLANs, let alone know how to set them up), but my Small Business router from Cisco does have the ability to set up separate VLANs *and restrict them from communicating with each other.* (Specifically, it allows setting a specific VLAN to not be able to communicate with other VLANs. I haven't tried any advanced setups with this.)

I use that feature to isolate any system on the wireless network from the wired network, but there's no reason in principle why you couldn't do the same with two wired segments. Both networks share the same uplink and are each able to access the Internet normally (well, as normally as you can have it with a NATed connection), but any host on the wireless network can only communicate with the Internet, not with any other VLAN. I haven't tried initiating communications from the unrestricted to the restricted VLAN, but at that point, you'd be looking at more or less implementation details, and if it was me, in your situation I'd set both VLANs to restricted in order to maintain logical full isolation between the two.

Assuming you don't want to get two separate Internet connections, and assuming your ISP is fine with your sharing the connection between the residents and the small business (check the fine print), that should provide you with the level of isolation you need. Consider a surge protector on both network connections as well, or someone's unprotected home PC could if you are unlucky damage the business' equipment as well.

Comment: I re-read your answer, and I realised: This would also mean blocking things like home media servers etc? Doesn't it?

Comment: @BlackMagic You probably can set up individual forwarding rules to allow certain traffic through; that depends on the specifics of the software you're using. However, your goal was to "make sure the residents can't communicate directly with the PC's on the business network", which VLAN isolation can give you.

Comment: So, If I for instance used one port to go to another router. Everyone on that 2nd router would be able to communicate with eachother. Am I correct? Or would that give IP clashes?

Comment: @BlackMagic You can achieve the same result by having two separate networks, each behind one NAT device, but you'll need one upstream IP for each. Isolated VLANs allow you to do the same thing with one. Beyond that it comes down to details of exactly how it's implemented.

Answer (score 1):

1. Buy a nice router, like a [MikroTik RB750 for about $40](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/11800283907218081406?q=mikrotik+RB750)
2. Connect each LAN to a distinct port
3. [Configure the router to actively block traffic that spans the two ports](http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=50190), using code like this:

   /ip firewall filter

   add action=drop chain=forward in-interface=ether3 out-interface=ether4

   add action=drop chain=forward in-interface=ether4 out-interface=ether3